# Adding or deducting a UI slider value to/from a total value stored in an HTML table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a cost estimator slider using a Jquery UI slider as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
       minValue: 0,
       maxValue: 10,
       stepping: 1,
       current: 5,
       slide: function(event, ui) {
     $('.cost').html((ui.value *50.00).toFixed(2)); }
 });
});
```

As you can see, I can get the value from the slider `ui.value` without any problem. Now I would like to be able to add or subtract the `$('.cost')` value to a total value (where `total=parseInt($('#total').html());`). The total contains the sum of some other calculations stored in an HTML table cell in the page as `<td id="total">Total</td>`.

I tried to do it by this way, but it doubled the total and it couldn't extract the cost from the total:

```
var total = parseInt($('#total').html());
var scost = parseInt($('.cost').html()); 
$('#total').html((total +  scost).toFixed(2));
```

How can I adjust the total value as the slider's value changes?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to recalculate the cost from scratch each time (i.e. do the whole calculation).

If you nudge it up or down each time one control changes, you'll have to cache the previous value for each control so you can reverse it before applying the new one (otherwise you end up adding or subtracting the same thing multiple times, as you have seen). This also risks problems with rounding errors. Unless your calculation is *really* complicated, recalculate it each time there's a change.

Comment: Hi Matthew, Thanks for your comment and editing my post!  I am new at JavaScript and Jquery as well.I really appriciate if you can give me some  more clear hints to do this or introduce me to an existing example.I tried to find a sample on the web but I could'nt find any thing!.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question, please consider accepting it as the answer by clicking on the tick.